# List changes in a RANGE of commits when changes revert other changes

Tags: git, diff, commit

Suppose I have the following git repo, in which a file was added in commit #2 and removed in commit #3:

```
commit de36dee94ab54ab61dd2c6e9164756c1a608bd13 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Keith <keith>
Date:   Tue Sep 25 09:57:45 2018 -0500

    #3

 foo.txt | 1 -
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)

commit 1fddf03367b9e2e4b65f96f4fc5db7d7d353f50c
Author: Keith <keith>
Date:   Tue Sep 25 09:57:37 2018 -0500

    #2

 foo.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

commit 4ab9494db091077879a74a47f83fe568a7efd133
Author: Keith <keith>
Date:   Tue Sep 25 09:57:23 2018 -0500

    #1

 README.md | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now suppose I'm interested in a summary of changes made in the *range* of commits #1-#3.
If I simply do `git diff HEAD 4ab9494db`, I will get no output since the repo is at the same state at the start and end; I'll never see that there was a file `foo.txt` that appeared and disappeared in that time frame. I could also do `git log --stat` as above, but assuming this was a much larger repo with a much longer history, that could get rather cumbersome.

Is there a way to get a succinct summary of all files changed, even if one change "cancels out" the other?

Comment: The short answer is no: these are output from `git diff --stat` and `git diff` only compares one pair of commits at a time. If you diff `<start>` vs `<end>`, that's your pair of commits; if the changes in between have canceled out, then there are no changes and `--stat` says nothing. What `git log` does is run a `git diff` (with options like `--stat` being optional) between each commit pair. You can do this yourself, and then manually (or using `awk` or something) sum up the `--stat` summaries, but that's a bit painful.

Comment: @torek Ah, I was afraid of that... Well, writing some sort of `git log --stat` parser could at least make for an interesting weekend project :)

Comment: You have two options: `diff A B` (shows the difference between commits A and B) or `log A..B` (shows all patches for all commits in the range A to B). If you only want to find "changed" files (regardless of how they changed), there's a way involving `log` and `--name-only`

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the file names:

```
git log --name-only --format='' | sort -u
```

`--name-only` will output all the files that are changed (added/deleted/modified) in a commit's patch.

Comment: Or something like `--name-status|sort -sk2 -usk1`

Comment: @jthill `sort -k1` will sort on the full line, if you only want to sort by the first field, `-k1,1` has to be used (this can be very confusing). From `man sort`: »EYDEF  is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the field;  both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.« TLDR: `sort -sk2 -usk1` is identical to `sort -usk1`, isn't it?

Comment: No, `-sk2 -usk1` sorts first on path, then on the status;  `-sk2 -usk1` gets whole-line dedup but preserves the path-first sorting.

Comment: @jthill thanks, TIL! (`-u` seems to be what's causing this behavior. elegant!)